# Как программно запустить из assets apk?

Tags: android

Как программно запустить из assets apk? чтобы появилось окно установки.

```
try{
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        File file=new File(getFilesDir()+"/apk");
        copyInputStreamToFile(getAssets().open("SuperUser.apk"),file);
        if (file.exists()){
            Log.e("asd","DA");
        }else {
            Log.e("asd","NET");
        }
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



private void copyInputStreamToFile( InputStream in, File file ) {
    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
        int len;
        while((len=in.read(buf))>0){
            out.write(buf,0,len);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала вам нужно скопировать ваш `.apk` файл на карту памяти.

Затем нужно стартовать установку через `startActivity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("путь к файлу")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Я этот код находил в рунете использовал не получилось. Пишет синтаксическая ошибка.... На каком то сайте находил.

Comment: ну так давайте код, будем смотреть где ошибка

Comment: Обновил вопрос в

Comment: ну так ошибка где?

Comment: При синтаксическом анализе пакета возникла неполадка

Comment: так это ошибка при установке. причем тут код